# SSRS 2008 Tablix bold just one row?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Is there a way, in SSRS to have just one row on a table (Tablix) highlighted if that one row has important information for the user.  Let's say, for example, I wanted the first row in bold.  How would I make that happen?

I think the syntax is `=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING)= 1, "#FF0000", Nothing)`

I managed to make my table morph from this:

```
Col 1        Col 2        Col 3    
[Col_1]        [Col_2]        [Col_3]
```

to this:

```
Col 1        Col 2        Col 3    
Expr    [Col_2]        [Col_3]
```

But should the expression for `Value` be:

```
=Fields!Col_1.Value

=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING)= 1, "#FF0000", Nothing)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background color property or font weight based on whatever your criteria is. You can use ROW_NUMBER() to check if it's the first row. Something like

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER("yourDatasetName") =1, "#FF0000", Nothing)
```

Comment: =IIF(ROWNUMBER("yourDatasetName") =1, "#FF0000", Nothing)
But I forgot where I can navigate to this point where I put in this information.  Please help.

Comment: In SSRS Visual Studio 2017, where do I find the place to the "=IIF" statements for a tablix?

Comment: Select the tablix, then click the grey row header on the left. In the properties panel (hit f4 if you don't see it) click the background color property and choose expression.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am new at this and so I am grateful.